# Graceful caching with Python and Redis

Tags: python, caching, redis

I want to cache data from external service in graceful manner: the old data, though expired, is being served until the worker successfully fetches new data. The data is not time-critical, but the lack of data (external service down) would prevent the service running, thus using a persistent cache.

Currently

- I store fetch timestamp in a separate Redis key
- I cache the data indefinitely until the worker fetches new one (I do not set expiration time)

Questions

- Is this correct way of doing graceful caching with Redis?
- Can I natively get key updated timestamp from Redis, so I do not need to store this information myself

This is the code:

```
def set_data(self, data):
    self.redis.set("bitcoinaverage", pickle.dumps(data))
    self.redis.set("bitcoinaverage_updated", calendar.timegm(datetime.datetime.utcnow().utctimetuple()))

def get_data(self):
    return pickle.loads(self.redis.get("bitcoinaverage"))

def is_up_to_date(self):

    last_updated = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(self.redis.get("bitcoinaverage_updated"))

    if not last_updated:
        return False

    return datetime.datetime.utcnow() < last_updated + self.refresh_delay

def tick(self):
    """ Run a periodical worker task to see if we need to update.
    """
    if not self.is_up_to_date():
        self.update()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have could work, but depends on how big you expect your data set to get. If I understand correctly, your current implementation will require you to run a worker pinging every key with tick(). This would be very, very expensive in terms of network back-and-forth in your current implementation since you'd have to go over the network, query Redis, and send the results back for every single key (possibly two queries if you need to update). If it's just for the two keys you mention, that's fine. If it's for more, [pipelines are your friend](http://redis.io/topics/pipelining).

If you wanted to be more elegant and robust, you could use [notifications](http://redis.io/topics/notifications) when your keys expire. The paradigm here would be, for each value you would set two keys: `k`, and `k_updated`. `k` would hold the actual value for the key, and `k_updated` would just be a dumb key with a TTL set for when you want `k` to be updated. When `k_updated` expires, you'll get a notification, and you can have a listener then immediately process this as a request for a new job to update `k` and set a new `k_updated`. This would use the [pubsub](http://redis.io/topics/pubsub) model, and you could have multiple subscribers and use a Queue to manage the new jobs, if you wanted to be very robust about it. The benefits of this system:

1. Keys will get updated immediately when they expire with no need to constantly query them to see if they need to be updated.
2. You can have multiple independent workers subscribed and listening for update tasks and manage new update jobs as they come in, so that if one update worker goes down, you don't lose updating until you bring the box back up.

This latter system could be overkill for your case if you don't have extreme speed or robustness needs, but if you do or plan to, it's something to consider.

Comment: Wooaaah. I didn't know Redis could do all this. Luckily I have only one single process worker, but I'll keep this in mind when I built something complex.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing will certainly work.

There's no way to natively get the timestamp that a key was inserted/updated, so you will have to either store it as you are at present or as an alternative you could change what you store for the bitcoinaverage key to include the timestamp (e.g. use some JSON to hold both the timestamp and pickled data, and store the JSON) however that makes your get_data() and is_up_to_date() more complex.

What happens in get_data() and is_up_to_date() if you have nothing stored for that key? Have you tested that condition?

Comment: Thanks! Currently the initial condition of missing data/timestamp is handled, but will add it there too.